# Display PDF in browser with some words highlighted?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to display a pdf in a browser in which I want some words highlighted. Is that possible in php? I'm currently using this code to display my pdf file

```
$fn=fopen($filename, "rb");
header( "Content-type: application/pdf");
while(!feof($fn)) {
 $buffer = fread($fn, 4096);
 print $buffer;
}
```

...but I don't know how to display it with highlighted words. I need a code that can do that, not necessarily in php....

Answer (score 0):

This first one is not exactly what you asked for, but may probably still be useful...

If you open the file with Acrobat, you can use commandline parameters to highlight a certain rectangle on the page. Example:

```
 acrobat.exe ^
   /a "page=14,highlight=100,100,200,110" ^
   "d:\path\to\example.pdf"
```

Here is something which matches more closely what you asked for, even if not by 100%. It opens the PDF alongside the search dialog, which is prefilled with the hits of the searched keywords, highlighting the first one:

```
 acrord32.exe ^
   /a #search="stackexchange football girls" ^
   "d:\path\to\example.pdf"
```

On Linux you would use:

```
 acroread \
   /a #search="stackexchange football girls" \
   "/path/to/example.pdf"
```

Now it's your own job finding out how to translate these Acrobat commandline calls into your PHP environment...  :-)

You'll find more info about this when you search the Adobe website for "PDF Open Parameters".

Comment: @Verne Jules: Yes, I told you it doesn't match your full expectations. But it is the closest you can get.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, looks like the js_api_reference can do something... Though it selects the nth word of a page, I don't know how to specify if it's the word I want...

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368425/highlight-search-terms-in-pdf) may help you. Or if you don't want to read, try [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/702-PHP-Searches-pdf-documents-for-text.html) =)

Comment: That doesn't work, and it just searches for a word in the pdf, it does not display the PDF itself with highlighted words...